# Convert arbitrary string values to timestamps SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, timestamp

I am wondering if there is a way to convert arbitrary string values (such as the examples below) to something that can be interpreted as a timestamp, perhaps in days.

| Dropdown_values | Desired Output(days) |
| --- | --- |
| 12 weeks | 84 |
| 1 Week 4 Days | 11 |
| 1 Year | 365 |
| 1 Year 1 Week 2 Days | 374 |

The idea I had was to split part out the values since they are all separated by spaces and then do the addition in a separate column, are there other (better) ways to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Those values are not timestamps, so you cant convert them to one. But you can cast those values directly to an `interval`, e.g. `cast(' 1 week 4 days' as interval)` that might already be enough depending on how you want to use that value. You can add an interval to a `timestamp` or `date` value

Comment: `justify_interval(CAST($1 AS interval))`?

Comment: `select extract(epoch from '12 Week'::interval)/86400; 84, select extract(epoch from '1 Year 1 Week 2 Days'::interval)/86400; 11, select extract(epoch from '1 Year 1 Week 2 Days'::interval)/86400; 374.25` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment as an answer:

```
select extract(epoch from '12 Week'::interval)/86400; 84
select extract(epoch from '1 Year 1 Week 2 Days'::interval)/86400; 11
select extract(epoch from '1 Year 1 Week 2 Days'::interval)/86400; 374.25
```

The above is how I usually deal with this sort of thing. Extract the `epoch` value from a the interval and then divide by the number of seconds in a day. It would be a good idea to read in the docs this [Interval input](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT) and [Interval output](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-OUTPUT) to understand how an interval is constructed and returned and the assumptions used. **Note**: the queries will return a `float` value not a `timestamp`. A value like `84` cannot be `timestamp`. You could turn it into an interval like: `84 * '1 day'::interval  84 days`. If at all possible it is good idea to store data as actual timestamps(start and end) and then derive intervals from that.

Comment: So this does work for most of the rows, but I'm getting an error stating Interval can't work with Year and Month parts. Another issue - '4 weeks' returns 28 days, '8 weeks' returns 86. Why might this be the case?

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific as I am not seeing it: `select extract(epoch from '8 weeks'::interval)/86400; 56` and `select extract(epoch from '1 year 4 months'::interval)/86400; 485.25`.

Comment: Looks like its an issue with Redshift. Your answer does help answer my question, thank you!